# wordpress php download pdf adds page html to front of file

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf

This used to work on my old hosting service. I just migrated to websynthesis and now when I download pdf files through browser, the html code for the download page is added to the pdf. The pdf file generated is ok when I download it directly, but not when downloaded through a browser. I am using the standard download script:

```
session_start();  
header("Content-disposition: attachment;    filename=$_SESSION[myfile.pdf]");  
header("Content-type: application/pdf");  
readfile($_SESSION[download-file.pdf]);
```

I have tried using many additional or alternate header statements with no success. Is there some additional header info I need to add?

Also filed support ticket with websynthesis

Comment: I'm guessing you need to call `exit();` after `readfile`. If that does not work, we need more information. Also, `$_SESSION[myfile.pdf]` does not make much sense. The key should be a string in quotes.

Comment: I have tried it with exit() and just tried it again and it doesn't make any difference. Also the filename is attached correctly to the downloaded file. When I open the file a text editor I can find where the pdf file begins after all the html that is at the front of the file.

Comment: What does the HTML contain? Where does it come from?

Comment: It's the HTML for the page with the shortcode call that contains the php download script.

Comment: Your running this code in a shortcode callback function?

Comment: yes. does that present a problem? Before that it was in the page template

Comment: Yes, the entire response should only contain the headers and the PDF file. You'll need to point the user to a URL you can use to respond with just the PDF. Use the `template_redirect` action or the AJAX URL to output the file. Also, you probably don't want to manually create a session. Maybe look into using user meta instead, if you need that functionality.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll create a template that only does the download. I use session upstream to pass file and processing info. Appreciate the response.